# Add steps to body test in the allure report Nunit3

Tags: c#, allure

I have written a simple NUnit3 test class and I want to generate an allure report for it.

```
[TestFixture]
[AllureNUnit]
public class SampleAllureTest
{
    [OneTimeSetUp]
    public void SetUp()
    {
         CreateDatabase();               
    }

    [OneTimeTearDown]
    public void CleanUp()
    {
        DropDatabase();
    }

    [Test]
    [AllureSeverity(SeverityLevel.critical)]
    public void CreateHierarchy()
    {
         // first step
         // second step
         // third step
    }
}
```

I have executed my test. After that, locally I am running a command to generate allure report.

```
allure serve .\allure-results\
```

My report is ready.

Open it in the browser and see a "suites" tab  for details about my test. It look like [image: here]

How Could I add additional description steps to the body that would be displayed in the allure report.

I would like to see something like [from demo allure report](https://demo.qameta.io/allure/#suites/195f684b9efefacfd69049419f325b4b/30e90f9ce75efea9/) where the open widget page test has some steps inside body.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can be achieved by the function `AllureLifecycle.Instance.WrapInStep`([from allure examples](https://github.com/unickq/allure-nunit/wiki/Samples))

```
[Test]
[AllureSeverity(SeverityLevel.critical)]
public void CreateHierarchy()
{
     AllureLifecycle.Instance.WrapInStep(() =>
     {
     // first step
     }, "first step");
     AllureLifecycle.Instance.WrapInStep(() =>
     {
        // second step
     }, "second step");
     AllureLifecycle.Instance.WrapInStep(() =>
     {
        // third step
     }, "third step");
}
```

We just wrap a pieces of test code and set name for them.